# Access created UI Elements in XAML WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I Have

```
class Canvas2:Canvas
{
}
```

class created in the same namespace. i can't use Canvas2 in XAML.
how can i make Canvas2 accessable in XAML code?
Im a newby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the xmlns like `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"` assuming Canvas2 is define in namespace WpfApplication1.

then you can use Canvas2 as `<local:Canvas2 x:Name="MyCanvas"/>`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you have to import your local namespace to the XAML too.
Check the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514546%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for sample.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty answer: Add the following line to your AssemblyInfo.cs

`[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation", "YourNamespace")]`

This way you add all classes in your Namespace to the default WPF-XML-Namespace. Then you can use your classes directly without adding an custom xml namespace.

Warning: Even if this works, it is not the recomended way. Especially I would not recommend this for larger projects because it could easily lead to name conflicts.

The correct way is to add a custom XML namespace like nit and AsitK described.